Is it possible to connect multiple SATA drives to a U.2 Port of a PC?
I have an Asus Pro WS x570 and I'm reading the document here and it mentions that a the Mini-SAS connector (U.2) can be used with a Mini-SAS HD cable to connect up to four SATA devices. Is this right?
The board already has four SATA ports. Does this mean it can have a total of 8 by using a Mini-SAS HD cable to the U.2 port? When I do an imagine search, it does show a lot of cables which I would think would work from that.
I've never used a U.2 port for anything before though. As I understand, it's meant to be used to connect an NVMe SSD directly to PCIe (similar to M.2) but can do this as well (also like M.2).
